# how to use datatables in rails 6.1.4?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, webpack, datatables

I am trying to use datatables.net in my new Rails project.

With this [tutorial](https://dev.to/mutatedbread/integrating-datatables-net-into-rails-with-webpacker-1aa1) I have managed to get to work, but in heroku they do not load the CSS and it does not have a good behavior.

```
GET https://example.com/assets/datatables.net-dt/css/jquery.dataTables.css net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)
```

Comment: It's just saying that it can't find the file. Maybe check the path properly

Answer (score 0):

This work for me: in config/environments/production.rb remove

```
config.assets.compile = false
```

this caused the CSS not to load.